# Julia - Previous and next values inside a for loop

Tags: for-loop, julia

Is there a way to operate with previous and next values inside for-loops in Julia? I could't find any answers from the Julia-documentation.

Example:

```
List1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
for letter in List1
   println(previous letter)
end
```

And this loop would give "a" as a result when it operates on "b", etc.

Comment: You may need to initialize the "previous" variable before executing the loop to something like an empty string value. For the first loop iteration, there is no "previous" value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without making simple things complicated:

```
List1 = ["a", "b", "c"]

for i = 2:length(List1)
    println("The previous letter of $(List1[i]) is $(List1[i-1])")
end
```

Outputs:

```
The previous letter of b is a
The previous letter of c is b
```

Comment: I like this solution because it is immediately understandable to anyone from (almost) any language.

Comment: On the other hand, it'll lose elements if List1 is an OffsetArray that doesn't start at 1.

Comment: Now Julia supports `for i = firstindex(List1)+1:lastindex(List1)` for custom indexing, which should not loose any elements.

Answer (score 5):

Another method is to use the `partition` iterator from IterTools.jl package:

```
using IterTools

List1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (prev,next) in partition(List1,2,1)
    @show prev
end
```

Gives:

```
prev = "a"
prev = "b"
```

`next` has the value of the current iteration (i.e. `"b"` and `"c"`) and the loop skips the iteration for the first value (with no `prev`).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `enumerate` function to get the previous index, something like:

```rb
julia> list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "a"
 "b"
 "c"

julia> enumerate(list1)
Enumerate{Array{String,1}}(["a", "b", "c"])

julia> collect(ans)
3-element Array{Tuple{Int64,String},1}:
 (1, "a")
 (2, "b")
 (3, "c")

julia> function prev(list::Vector{String})
           enumeration = enumerate(list)
           for (index, element) in enumeration
               if index == 1
                   continue
               else
                   println("The previous letter of $element is $(list[index - 1]).")
               end
           end
       end
prev (generic function with 1 method)

julia> prev(list1)
The previous letter of b is a.
The previous letter of c is b.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found one way to do it myself:

```
List1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
for letter in List1
    if  !(findn(List1 .== letter) == [1])
        println("The previous letter of ", letter, " is ", List1[findn(List1 .== letter)-1])
    end
end
```

Output:

```
The previous letter of b is String["a"]
The previous letter of c is String["b"]
```

Now only problem is that the results are some kind of string-arrays.